# RabbitMQ Cluster fails with error no endpoints available

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, rabbitmq, istio

I am trying to setup `RabbitMQ Operator + RabbitMQ Cluster` on K8S using Terraform

I installed `cert-manager` and `rabbitmq-cluster-operator` successfully.  I am trying to create `RabbitMQCluster` using the following [link](https://github.com/mateothegreat/terraform-kubernetes-rabbitmq-cluster/blob/main/main.tf)

However `RabbitMQCluster` failed with the following message and output is given below

```
 Message:               The service has no endpoints available
 Reason:                NoEndpointsAvailable
```

**Output (Tailored output)**

```
[root@re-ctrl02 rbmq]# kubectl describe RabbitmqCluster -n rabbitmq-system
Name:         basic-cluster
Namespace:    rabbitmq-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  rabbitmq.com/v1beta1
Kind:         RabbitmqCluster
Spec:
  Image:  rabbitmq:3.8.18-management
  Override:
    Stateful Set:
      Spec:
        Template:
          Spec:
            Containers:
              Name:  rabbitmq
              Resources:
              Name:  rabbitmq
              Resources:
  Rabbitmq:
    Additional Config:                    hostname = "https://localhost"
                  host = "https://localhost"
                  port = "5672"
                  nodes = "rabbit@localhost"
                  default_vhost = "/"
                  default_user = "admin"
                  default_pass = "admin"
                  default_user_tags.administrator = true

  Replicas:  1
  Service:
    Type:                            NodePort
  Termination Grace Period Seconds:  604800
  Tls:
Status:
  Binding:
    Name:  basic-cluster-default-user
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2021-08-09T13:51:42Z
    Message:               0/1 Pods ready
    Reason:                NotAllPodsReady
    Status:                False
    Type:                  AllReplicasReady
    Last Transition Time:  2021-08-09T13:51:42Z
    Message:               The service has no endpoints available
    Reason:                NoEndpointsAvailable
    Status:                False
    Type:                  ClusterAvailable
    Last Transition Time:  2021-08-09T13:51:42Z
    Reason:                NoWarnings
    Status:                True
    Type:                  NoWarnings
    Last Transition Time:  2021-08-09T13:51:42Z
    Reason:                Initialising
    Status:                Unknown
    Type:                  ReconcileSuccess
```

I am not sure to `which service it refers` to and what entries should be added in file `main.tf`

Kindly let me know what am I doing wrong

Comment: , based on your history on this site. Suggesting to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. A describe of the statefulset says:

```
kubectl describe statefulsets.apps basic-cluster
```

you need to add the namespace.

> Warning  FailedCreate      8s (x12 over 18s)  statefulset-controller
> create Pod examplerabbitmq-server-0 in StatefulSet
> examplerabbitmq-server failed error: Internal error occurred: failed
> calling webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post
> "https://istio-sidecar-injector.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=30s":
> service "istio-sidecar-injector" not found

So likely you need to install istio

- curl -L https://istio.io/downloadIstio | sh -
- cd istio-1.14.0/
- export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH
- istioctl install --set profile=demo -y
- kubectl label namespace  istio-injection=enabled
- kubectl apply -f rabbitmq.yaml
- kubectl describe statefulsets.apps examplerabbitmq

> Normal  SuccessfulCreate  2m49s  statefulset-controller  create Pod
> examplerabbitmq-server-2 in StatefulSet examplerabbitmq-server
> successful